# numpy conditional list membership element wise

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[0,1],
              [2,3]])
```

I have a list of values to keep:

```
vals_keep = [1,2]
```

I want to test for list membership for each element in the array. Something like:

```
mask = a in vals_keep
```

The result I want:

```
array([[False,  True],
       [True,  False]])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**`isin`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

> **`isin`** is an element-wise function version of the python keyword **`in`**

```
np.isin(a, vals_keep)

array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False]])
```

An added benefit of **`isin`** is that it's flexible with arrays of different dimensions:

```
a = np.arange(4).reshape(1,2,2,1)
np.isin(a, vals_keep)

array([[[[False],
         [ True]],

        [[ True],
         [False]]]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way using broadcasting:

```
In [35]: (a[:, :, None] == vals_keep).any(2)
Out[35]: 
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False]])
```

Which is faster than `isin` for small arrays (less than 100 rows):

```
In [37]: %timeit np.isin(a, vals_keep)
22 µs ± 728 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [38]: %timeit (a[:, :, None] == vals_keep).any(2)
12.6 µs ± 95.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For large arrays it's better to use `isin` because broadcasting in 3D is not very efficient for large arrays/matrices.